# How to prevent a docker container from being attached by multiple users?

Tags: docker, container

When you run docker containers you can list running containers by using `docker ps`

Then you can attach them by `docker attach <container id>`

The trouble is that all people that can attach the running container at the same time as you, and will see what you are doing at the same time, that could be cool for online courses, but not very nice at works.

How can I prevent that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Docker Sub commands using sudo**

One solution is to provide them with selected docker commands using `sudo` and do not provide the `docker attach`, or `docker run` command.

You can restrict them to run only `docker ps`

Please see the documentation or man page of `sudo` for how to provide only the subcommands that you want to allow to users. Providing docker access using `sudo` is the recommended method anyway, instead of putting users in a docker group straight away.

**Example:**

Either run `visudo` or create a file under `/etc/sudoers.d/<username>` and create a line for each command you need to allow: ( this is kind of rough , in production I suppose you will be managing sudo config using some config management tool like `puppet` , `chef` or `ansible` that will do this for you once you write the config code )

```
<user_account> ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/docker ps
```

More details:

[Details](https://forums.docker.com/t/restricting-users-ability-to-execute-docker-sub-commands-and-or-better-approach/29020)

**Note:** I had such a use case where an automated bot user needed only the docker pull command so I just restricted that account to run docker pull only through sudo. This approach makes sure:

- **availability ( provide what is needed )**
- **principle of least privilege**

Comment: This is an interesting idea, but probably important to recognize that it has limitations, as the sudo command doesn't understand the operation of the underlying Docker daemon.  Whilst restricting a user to a single command seems like it would work (e.g. `docker ps`) as soon as you allow `docker run` in any form, all bets are likely off (absent other controls like user namespacing)

Comment: yes , one needs to be careful to allow some command

Comment: Thanks for the details that is really helpful

Answer (score 6):

If a user on a Docker Engine host has rights to execute docker commands (via either having sudo privileges, or membership of the docker group) there is no way (with the base Docker product) of restricting them from attaching to containers running on the host

Effectively providing docker access is the same as providing root on the host.

So to prevent it, the key is don't let other users have rights to run docker commands on that host.